# Minimize Microsoft Edge browser from C# not working

Tags: c#, .net, browser, microsoft-edge

I am trying to minimize the Microsoft Edge browser through C#. All the other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer are working fine except Microsoft Edge.

Can anybody please help me on this.

Here is my code.

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge");
        //var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

         foreach (var process in processes)
            ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 2);
    }
```

You can try uncommenting Chrome process it is working.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick (pretty self-explanatory and I've provided comments just in case):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace EdgeApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        public delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        public const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;
        public const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Enumerate over windows.
            EnumWindows((handle, param) =>
            {
                // Get the class name. We are looking for ApplicationFrameWindow.
                var className = new StringBuilder(256);
                GetClassName(handle, className, className.Capacity);

                // Get the window text. We're looking for Microsoft Edge.
                int windowTextSize = GetWindowTextLength(handle);
                var windowText = new StringBuilder(windowTextSize + 1);
                GetWindowText(handle, windowText, windowText.Capacity);

                // Check if we have a match. If we do, minimize that window.
                if (className.ToString().Contains("ApplicationFrameWindow") && 
                    windowText.ToString().Contains("Microsoft Edge"))
                {
                    ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
                }

                // Return true so that we continue enumerating,
                // in case there are multiple instances.
                return true;
            }, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can easily verify, the process you're looking at has no main window. It's handle is `0`. Thus you're not minimising anything.

UWP apps are (or can be) a bit different from normal Win32 applications. While the Edge content processes have a window title, you cannot minimise Edge by using that window handle either. The actual process that window belongs to is `ApplicationFrameHost`. You may need to filter the main window title appropriately if there are multiple of them.

Comment: Thank you @Joey. If you have any idea how can i do this, can you please share your code.